# BGE play animation in other object using button

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

I need help with my game engine project.
I try to create a text object that move to center of viewport when i click a button. I've try using action actuator, but it affected the button, not the text.

Here's the animation that i wanted to do

[image: Button]

The text first at the right side of camera, and when i clicked that button, the text move to the center of viewport like this

[image: action]

If anyone can help, please let me know how to do that, or maybe someone can give me a link to tutorial that related to my problem.
Another thing, is there a way that i can make my text dynamic, based on what button i click? like when i click the white button, the text value is 1, and when i click another button, the text value change to 2?

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE! Could you upload your .blend or a stripped down version of it to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and edit the question to post the code given to you? Also if you have another question that is not related to your main question then please post it as a separate question. It's easier for us to answer one question than two at once because one doesn't risk having an answer that's wrong and correct at the same time, and it's easier for you to select a correct answer if you split your question into multiple ones.

Answer (score 1):

You need to play the action at the text rather than the button.

For inter-object communication I suggest to activate a message actuator e.g. with subject "button clicked".

On receipt of the message "button clicked" the text object can start playing the action.